# What is the song being played in the suicide scene in Disconnect?

Tags: soundtrack, disconnect

I'm not sure wether this question should be posted in the Movies & TV or in the Music site, but I don't know wether this song was composed for the film or not so I'll post it here:

What is the song being played in the scene where Ben commits suicide in the movie [Disconnect](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1433811/?ref_=nv_sr_1)?

[This is the scene I'm talking about](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVF71oim_XY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the "[What Song](http://www.what-song.com/Movies/Soundtrack/1229/Disconnect)" website, it is "Like a Dog" by Jayme Ivison and Bryan Austin.

This [youtube of the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHytIM51ERs) appears to match it, starting about 1:40ish into the song video.